# Date restrictions on user input in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to have a date entry box which has the following restrictions. Date must be today's date or earlier, but not more than 1 year previous. I have the following line:

```
if (myFDGDT - todayDate > 0 || (myFDGDT - todayDate)/86400000 < -365)
```

The first portion of that creates the appropriate alert when some enters a date after today's date. Not sure about the best way to cap the entry to a year previous. Attempted a few items, but the above was just an example of my last attempt. This is also written in a dependency and not in the Global JavaScript of our entry client.

Comment: Are your dates `Date` objects or Unix timestamps?

Comment: Be aware about working with dates and time on client-side, a lot of people has their clocks with an incorrect date/time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet that will generate a Date object that is one year ago. You can compare against it as needed using greater than/less than operators.

```
var oneyear = new Date('01/01/1971'); // from unix epoch
var now = new Date();
var oneyearago = new Date(now - oneyear);
alert(oneyearago);
```

Comment: This works, but it seems unnecessarily tricky. Why not use setYear(now.getFullYear() - 1)? I'm curious if your method has advantages I'm not seeing.

Comment: Valid point. At the time of writing I was conceptually thinking of subtracting a time span. Setting the year works too. FYI Mozilla dev network lists setYear() as deprecated so you'd probably want to use getUTCFullYear()/setUTCFullYear().

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the tip. And for the cool 1971 trick. That would never have occurred to me in a million years.

Answer (score 0):

If you are manipulating dates a lot in your app you should consider using the momentjs library. For your problem the solution would be something like:

```
    var momentdate = moment(date);
    if (momentdate.isAfter(momentdate.add(1, 'year') ||
     momentdate.isBefore(momentdate.startOf('day')) {
      // Invalid date?
    }
```

Hope this helps.